# Android app development - Layout designing

Tags: java, android, layout, sdk, piano

i'm new to Android development. I'm working on a new app(piano style) and using Android Studio. I'm trying to design the layout using the ready to be placed buttons. However, i'm having problems placing them where i want, f.e. the piano keys, which cannot be place the one next to another and with a same size. I have read that's because Android devices are in many sizes(more specifically the screens), not like Iphones, which come in one size for each generation.

I've searched the net to find a way to do that, but nothing really helped. Any ideas that could help??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was developing piano app in past, and you shoudn't make keys in layout, you should intead draw it by yourself(with drawables). This is whole project which i used to create piano : https://github.com/TheHiddenDuck/custom_view_keyboard, this is post about it, but you should know that it's in russian : http://habrahabr.ru/post/176643/ (so if aren't familiar with this language you should skip this post) anyway code will do the trick, and you can feel free to ask about some parts of it, because i've made a project around this code

Comment: Thanks for your response Nik. That will prove very helpful. However, i get 4 error like the one below:

Error:(11, -1) Android Resource Packaging: [custom_view_keyboard-master] C:\Users\Livas\Desktop\custom_view_keyboard-master\.idea\AndroidManifest.xml:11: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/ic_launcher').

I've searched for solutions but w/o success.

Comment: Hi Nik.Could i contact you in any way in order to ask some questions if possible? Thanks!

Comment: @GalinhoSalonica, oh sure, i'm just busy wuth my study and work now, but you can feel free to emal me to nikolay.sh@it-dimension.com and i'll replay as soon as i can

Comment: Thanks a lot Nik. I don't want to interupt. I'll ask only in great need. I really appreciate. :)